# Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.solr:solr-core:jar:8.0.0 -> org.restlet.jee:org.restlet:jar:2.3.0

Tags: solrj, restlet

After including:

```
<dependency>
<groupid>org.apache.solr</groupid>
<artifactid>solr-core</artifactid>
<version>8.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and running mvn clean package i have this error:

Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.solr:solr-core:jar:8.0.0 -> org.restlet.jee:org.restlet:jar:2.3.0

In [mvnrepository org.restlet/2.3.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.restlet.jee/org.restlet/2.3.0) it says:
Note: this artifact is located at Spring Plugins repository (https://repo.spring.io/plug...

According to this: [spring notice of permission](https://spring.io/blog/2022/12/14/notice-of-permissions-changes-to-repo-spring-io-january-2023#comment-6310741765) I tried either:

```
<repository>
<id>spring-snapshot</id>
<name>Spring Snapshot Repository</name>
<url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
<snapshots>
<enabled>true</enabled>
</snapshots>
</repository>
```

or:

```
<repository>
<id>spring-milestone</id>
<name>Spring Milestone Repository</name>
<url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
</repository>
```

and none works.

I even did mvn -U clean package to force check the update on the remote repositories but not working.

Comment: Created a comment in here and waiting for an answer:
https://spring.io/blog/2022/12/14/notice-of-permissions-changes-to-repo-spring-io-january-2023#comment-6310741765